# How do I print the value of a theano variable whenever it is evaluated?

Tags: python, theano

I'm using lasagne and theano to build a convolutional neural network, and I'm having issues trying to follow the printdebugging examples in http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/debug_faq.html#how-do-i-step-through-a-compiled-function

My function looks like this with G and Y being theano tensors

```
def loss_function(self, G, Y_):
    # Split batch into pairs
    G1, G2 = G[0::2], G[1::2]
    Y = Y_[:G.shape[0] // 2]
    # Energy of training pairs
    E = T.abs_((G1 - G2)).sum(axis=1)
    Q = 2
    genuine_loss = (1 - Y) * (2 / Q) * (E ** 2)
    imposter_loss = (Y) * 2 * Q * T.exp((-2.77 * E) / Q)
    loss = genuine_loss + imposter_loss
    avg_loss = T.mean(loss)
    return ave_loss
```

so the output ave_loss should be a symbolic expression that when compiled and executed with input data will result in computing the average loss over a batch of training images.

What I want to do is put a symbolic print expression in here so that whenever the ave_loss is computed it prints the contents of G.

But right now I'm stuck just trying to get something to print before and after

```
def loss_function(self, G, Y_):

    # Inject a symbolic expression to print something before and after G is used. 

    def pre_func(i, node, fn):
        print('Before')

    def post_func(i, node, fn):
        print('After')

    dbgfunc = theano.function([G], [G],
                              mode=theano.compile.MonitorMode(
                                  pre_func=pre_func,
                                  post_func=post_func))
    G = dbgfunc()

    # Split batch into pairs
    G1, G2 = G[0::2], G[1::2]
    Y = Y_[:G.shape[0] // 2]
    # Energy of training pairs
    E = T.abs_((G1 - G2)).sum(axis=1)
    Q = 2
    genuine_loss = (1 - Y) * (2 / Q) * (E ** 2)
    imposter_loss = (Y) * 2 * Q * T.exp((-2.77 * E) / Q)
    loss = genuine_loss + imposter_loss
    avg_loss = T.mean(loss)
    return ave_loss
```

The above code does not work, and I'm not really sure how to manipulate theano.function to make it work.

What I'm attempting to do is create an identity function that accepts G and returns G without modifying it, but prints pre_func and post_func along the way.

How to you use theano.function (or theano.printing.Print) to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't help you with the printing approach since
I have never used the print myself. But.. wouldn't it
be possible to return G together with the ave_loss.
Then you can look at the contents...

something like:

```
def loss_function(self, G, Y_):
    ...
    G = dbgfunc()
    ...
    return ave_loss, G


G = T.matrix('G') 
Y_ = T.matrix('Y')

ave_loss, G_prime = loss_function(G, Y_)

f = function([G, _Y], [ave_loss, G_prime])

print( f(...) )
```

EDIT:

I just saw that the contents of **G** don't seem to be changing.
Why do you want to print it anyways. Since the print also prevents
Theano from some optimisations if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is just a dummy example. I'm trying to make sure that the values are within a specific range. I'm not going to have these enabled permanently. I guess using a separate function is an ok workaround.